# Way in Bower to snapshot and recreate snapshot?

Tags: version-control, bower

I want to recreate my system as it was a month ago, but if I run "bower install" now, even with the bower.json I had a month ago, it may install different versions of the components than it did a month ago.

So I figure I need to generate a snapshot of version numbers of what bower has installed, a simple text file is fine, and then later be able to tell bower to install all those versions.  Is there a way to do this with bower?

Closest I can come is running "bower list" for a snapshot and then writing a fancy shell script that can parse that, pull out components and version numbers, remove repeats, and "bower install" each one.